# Do I need to delete a child context?

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I have created a child context and subsequently saved or rolled back any changes made within it, do I need to delete or remove it? If so, how? My assumption is that I will create a new child context when I need one again.

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Please post some CODE

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. I assume you may be referring to Core Data, but you should provide a better description and code examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but Marcus Zarra (author of a Core Data book -- see: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/) has said that creating child contexts is very cheap and you should just let them go and create new ones.  To do that, just stop referring to them once you are done (e.g. set variables to nil) and let ARC deal with it.

There are other schools of thought that you shouldn't even use child contexts at all -- to see why, read the [objc.io book on Core Data](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/).